# Scheme names with * as suffix

Tags: scheme, racket

There are some forms in the tradition of Scheme that are named the same as *more primitive* forms but with a `*` appended as a suffix.

Some examples

[let*](https://docs.racket-lang.org/r5rs/r5rs-std/r5rs-Z-H-7.html?q=let*#%25_idx_130)
[define*](https://docs.racket-lang.org/compatibility/compatibility-package.html?q=let*#%28form._%28%28lib._compatibility%2Fpackage..rkt%29._define%2A%29%29)

Now for these derived forms the explanation is that you get visibility of your previous bindings
in the later bindings kind of a `letrec` style but creating one id at a time instead of all at once (?).

Now this pattern extends thought to other forms and some packages have custom macros with the `*` symbol as a suffix (`define-ratbag*`). Is this some implicit convention of the Scheme tribe, is this documented somewhere?

Comment: I think it all comes from `let*`.  That seems to have originated in Maclisp, (Lisp 1.5 didn't have `let` even and I am not sure Interlisp did either).  `let*` is just an obvious 'I need another name like this one' thing I think, and `let*`'s critical purpose is to reduce indentation really.  Then once you have that, everything that has semantics a bit like it probably ends up with an `x*` name.  But I don't think it's a rule: I use `x*` for other sorts of variants, for sure.

Comment: @tfb as Kleene star, `__*` can be regarded as "many" or "sequence" after all. so maybe that was the inspiration.

Comment: @WillNess: yes, that's plausible I think.  I suspect it is lost in time though.  There probably are maclisp people who are still around to answer, but they may not remember.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several things that a `*` suffix might mean:

- *sequential scoping* like `let*`, as opposed to *independent scoping* like `let`. Examples: [`with-syntax*`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/syntax-util.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fsyntax..rkt%29._with-syntax%2A%29%29) is like `with-syntax`, but each right-hand side is in the scope of previous clauses.
- *sequential effect* as opposed to *independent effect*. Examples: [`parameterize*`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/parameters.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmore-scheme..rkt%29._parameterize%2A%29%29) is like `parameterize`, but each parameter's new value is evaluated with the previous parameters updated to their new values; [`with-handlers*`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/exns.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmore-scheme..rkt%29._with-handlers%2A%29%29) is like `with-handlers`, but each exception handler is called in a context with the previous exception handlers installed.
- *like the other thing, but multiple times*. Examples: [`remove*`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._remove%2A%29%29) is like `remove`, but removes *all* occurrences of the given element; [`regexp-match*`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/regexp.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._regexp-match%2A%29%29) is like `regexp-match`, but finds all matches.
- *like the other thing, but the final argument acts like a rest-argument*. Examples [`append*`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._append%2A%29%29), [`list*`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._list%2A%29%29): `(append* vss)` is equivalent to `(apply append vss)`.
- *like the other thing, but accepts multiple arguments*. Examples: [`hash-set*`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/hashtables.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._hash-set%2A%29%29) is like `hash-set`, but accepts multiple key-value pairs.
- *like the other thing, but just a bit different*. Examples: [`write-bytes-avail*`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Byte_and_String_Output.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._write-bytes-avail%2A%29%29) is like `write-bytes-avail`, except it never blocks; [`date*`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/time.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._date%2A%29%29) is like `date` except it adds nanosecond and time-zone-name fields; [`call-with-input-file*`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/file-ports.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._call-with-input-file%2A%29%29) is like `call-with-input-file` except closes the input port on escapes. In this usage, you can read `*` as Scheme/Racket's version of a prime suffix.

Comment: The very last one is the actual meaning. All the other ones are different ways it is different with some specific patterns :-)

Comment: perhaps Kleene star was the original inspiration. it can be regarded as "many" or "sequence" after all, and all your points except the very last can be so too.

Comment: The best way to think about it is that you want a `foo'`, but that's an invalid identifier, so `foo*`...